# ng test and ng serve fails with "An unhandled exception occurred: Invalid or unexpected token"

Tags: angular

In my Angular8 application, both ng serve and ng test was working fine till yesterday.  But today, both command fails with error.

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Invalid or unexpected token See "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-jcwQWX\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

angular-errors.log file

```
[error] C:\Users\Username\Documents\GWM\GWM-Front-end\node_modules\webpack\lib\node\NodeMainTemplatePlugin.js:2



SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at compileFunction (<anonymous>)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892:18)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:849:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Username\Documents\GWM\GWM-Front-end\node_modules\webpack\lib\node\NodeTemplatePlugin.js:8:32)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:849:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Username\Documents\GWM\GWM-Front-end\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\resource_loader.js:16:28)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:958:30)
```

When I tried npm install/update, it fails.

```
C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\iconv-lite\lib\streams.js:1 {��{��{��{��{��{��{��{��{��{��{��{��{��{��{��d]��KC��RJ��VM��XO��YP��YP��YP��YP��YP��YP��YP��YP��YP��YP��YP��YP��YP��YP��YP��YP��A<Y

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892:18)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:849:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\iconv-lite\lib\index.js:144:9)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
```

Can someone advise what is the issue and how to make ng s and ng test run fine?

Answer (score 3):

Most probable reason that you are facing this error is because your `node_modules` folder is not configured correctly, may be you have downloaded the project from some other source along with `node_modules`, so the packages need to be reinstalled again

`sudo rm -rf node_modules`

`sudo npm i`

Comment: Sometimes i face the same error (without touching node_modules at all) and this is the only thing that resolves it. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

After removing and reinstalling iconv-lite package, when running ng test command, now the error in angular-errors.log file indicated webpack library.  So, removed and reinstalled webpack.  Now ng test command and ng s works fine.

Answer (score 0):

after restarting my system this issue got resolved. I don't know why but it worked